# Discord.js Token Invalid

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
require("dotenv").config()
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [] })

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg.content === "ping") {
        msg.reply("pong");
    }
})

client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

```
if (!token || typeof token !== 'string') throw new DiscordjsError(ErrorCodes.TokenInvalid);
                                                   ^

Error [TokenInvalid]: An invalid token was provided.
    at Client.login (C:\Users\johnw\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\Client.js:214:52)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\johnw\WebstormProjects\DiscordBot\index.js:15:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:82:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'TokenInvalid'
}

Node.js v19.0.0
```

**ENV FILE** - This is an old Token

```
TOKEN=MTA0NTI0ODI0NjIyMzc0NTAzNA.G36OM9.q2GxfF8ZOXqIjkKcAAnOsH_XbuC_vbgLDuOLT8
```

I am trying to run my bot but it always tells me that my token is invalid.

I tried refreshing my token and using the new one but even this won't help.

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VGzu.png)

Comment: If that is your real discord token you need to go and invalidate it asap.

Comment: What do you see when you `console.log(process.env.TOKEN);`?

Comment: This is an old token btw I just put it there for demonstration purposes.
I actually see nothing when I run console.log().

Comment: First of all I'd suggest moving `require("dotenv")` to the first line. Secondly are you sure the `.env` file is in the correct location (maybe add a screenshot of your file structure)?

Comment: I added my folder structure

Comment: Alright, by default the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package looks at a file called `.env` not `process.env`. So either rename the file or use the `path` option in the config like `require('dotenv').config({ path: 'process.env' })`

Comment: I changed it to .env now and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: Questions should be answered as answers, not comments

Answer (score 1):

Rename `process.env` (the file) to `.env`. That should fix the problem.

Answer (score -3):

First of all, you shouldnt post your actual bots token online. Also it seems you are using env file, i personally just recommend using a json file for it since its much more convinient.

that way you can just do

```
const { token } = require('./config.json');
```

it looks like the error prompts that the TOKEN var isnt a string, so if you want to use env file. Cast it to string before parsing it into the param.